# Running AppleScript via shell(bash/zsh) expands window to height of desktop. How can I make it fit?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, bash

I have a shell script in which I use osascript to display a prompt to the user for selection from a list. The problem here is, when the script is executed via shell, the osascript window size is extended to the size of the screen height, filling the list selection with empty space. When I run the same osascript code from the script editor, the selection fits to the window size. Is there a way to make the window fit the list items (like in the second picture listed below)?

Here's the sample script:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
set magtitles to {"A", "B", "C", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "y", "Z"}
choose from list magtitles
```

Here's how it looks like when executed via shell:

[image: Script started with shell]

And here's how it looks like when executed via Script Editor:

[image: Script started with Script Editor]

I have tested it on Big Sur 11.1 and Big Sur 11.2 beta, both with same results.

Comment: What happens if you hold Opt & click the green dot in the larger window, then quit & re-launch? What happens if you manually shrink the window, then quit & re-launch? Apps should remember their last window size, but I'm not sure if a shell-script window will do that.

Comment: Nothing changes, basically. When I run the script again it shows it the same as previously, the state is not saved.

Comment: OK, was just a thought. Sorry, idk in that case.

Comment: I just tested the **AppleScript**  `osascript` _shell script_ under **macOS Big Sur** 11.1 and cannot replicate your issue. The _dialog window_ opens the height of the `list`, showing **A** thru **Z** with no blank space under **Z**.

Comment: How exactly are you running the script? I have it set as "test.sh" and just execute it from the Terminal app by running "./test.sh" in the current directory. Also, which shell are you using? I tried it with both zsh and bash, it made no difference.